# Best way to fetch and parse JSON in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, json, ios4

My iPhone app will call a JSON Api to load text and images. I've seen some JSON frameworks like http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html

How to fetch and parse JSON in an iOS App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the best way to do it is indeed by using [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for json parsing and generation, and [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for the http communications.

This is my setup, and it's wonderfully simple to work with.